# Create a file and add it to a folder with Sharepoint's Api Rest using Postman

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I use this call: https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/ Folder Name')/Files/add(url ='a.txt', overwrite = true).The file is inserted correctly but I don't know what to add so that I can fill the rest of the columns of the library of documents.But it can be done in the same call, it doesn't matter. But I need to modify the value in a record of a document library

Comment: Do you want to update the meta data of the uploaded file?

Comment: If it is what I want if it could be done in the same call better

Answer (score 0):

Warrior,

Do you want to update values of other columns after uploading a file to a library? If so, you may hava a look below demo:

```html
function getItem(file) {
    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: file.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });

    return call;
}

function updateItemFields(item) {
    var now = new Date();
    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
            "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/Items(" +
            item.Id + ")",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.DocumentsItem" },
            CoordinatorId: _spPageContextInfo.userId,
            Year: now.getFullYear()
        }),
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": item.__metadata.etag,
            "X-Http-Method": "MERGE"
        }
    });

    return call;
}
```

You need to put this operation in a separated request.

BR